# Does Gradle require JDK to compile Java?

Tags: java, gradle

Does **Gradle** requires **JDK** to compile **Java source files**? 
or it is using its own internal compiler?

Thanks in advance

Comment: JDK. Because JRE has no Java Compiler included

Comment: we need the set the JDK

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short version:** JRE for installing and running, Groovy build script compiled by Gradle own compiler, JDK for Java source code compilation.

**Long version:** There are multiple points of interest:

**1) Installing & running**

In order to install Gradle and run Gradle build you need a JDK or JRE which version is at least 7.

Gradle uses mainly Groovy as a language but it comes with its own library and ignores any other Groovy library that is installed. Therefore the compiler is the Groovy compiler of the Groovy library that Gradle comes with.

As a side note, you can also use Kotlin for scripting builds as [described here](https://blog.gradle.org/kotlin-meets-gradle). Which of course involves a Kotlin compiler.

You can check the JVM version by running `gradle -v`.

This means that during installation the runtime configured in `JAVA_HOME` will be used.

Also the same happens for running a build, unless you are explicitly overriding `JAVA_HOME` in `gradle.properties` using the following property `org.gradle.java.home`. This property and others are defined [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

`JAVA_HOME` can point to a JDK or JRE. In this case does suffice to have only a JRE installation.

**2) Source Code Compilation**

To remove any confusion, source code, means that you have your project sources, written in a language, which need to be compiled into bytecode. At previous point the code being written is the actual build script code which is a separate thing, compiled and handled by Gradle.

Source code is being compiled using Gradle plugins, being it java, groovy, kotlin, or anything else.

You can compile your JAVA source code by using the [`java`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html) plugin or the newer [`java-library`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html) plugin. The two are similar.

The JDK being used will be the one configured in `JAVA_HOME` or can be explicitly defined in `gradle.properties` using the following property `org.gradle.java.home`.

`JAVA_HOME` needs to point to the JDK not a JRE for this case.

As stated above, Gradle can only run on Java 7 or higher. But it can be configured to compile, run, test, javadoc for Java 6 by following [these steps](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_cross_compilation). Therefore this advanced customization can be used to handle some corner cases which may not have a resolution in simply changing [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

The two plugins provide also two properties:

- `sourceCompatibility` - Java version compatibility to use when compiling Java source
- `targetCompatibility` - Java version to generate classes for.

These are related to the source language version used as input and the target bytecode version to be generated.